# How can you implement a jQuery feature without having IE prompt users with an Active X warning?

Tags: jquery, activex, slideshow, user-experience

Essentially, I want to implement a jQuery feature on a site that I'm building, but I don't want Internet Explorer users to have to click "Allow Blocked Content". The feature works fine with Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. It's only IE that prompts the users with the Active X warning.

I'm using the following jQuery cycle plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

I thought that I might simply have to live with the fact that users have to click on the Active X message when they use the site, but Zendesk (www.zendesk.com) is using the same implementation and that site doesn't prompt me with the warning.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: not really sure the jquery is responsible for this, is there something else on the page that is an activex control?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's probably because you're running the page locally. IE doesn't like local pages to run javascript and will always complain about it. Once you have it as a website (even on localhost) it shouldn't complain anymore.

Comment: You guys were right, the warning was occurring from opening the HTML file locally. Once I posted it the Active X messages went away.

Answer (score 4):

Is it because you are running locally/from file? Try on a remote server. Does the problem persist? To get rid of it locally, try adding the "[mark of the web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx)"

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a live server. Serached the web for answers and kept finding info saying it was because you're testing on a local server or you need to apply MOTW. No. Turns out there's a bug fix that needs to be applied to the jquery script itself to get rid of it.

http://dev.jquery.com/changeset/6268

Worked for me. Also, make sure the script is not the minified version.

Answer (score 0):

Some effects in IE are implemented via an ActiveX plugin (fade, etc).  If you have the browser set to always warn about ActiveX in all cases you can not stop these messages.  However, there are settings which don't show these warnings eg trusted site lists.

Comment: I would love to see a link to some kind of documentation of this.

Comment: @Jørn : Me too, the only way I found it out was opening a support ticket with microsoft.

Comment: Side note: This may have been fixed in more recent versions of IE -- I'm not at the company where we had this problem anymore.